# Interactive mode breaks with "TypeError: exec() globals must be a dict, not builtin_function_or_method"

Tags: python

With this code

```py
import code
# ... some code

code.interact(local=locals)
```

I get the error message after everything I type in the Python Shell:

```
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> 1+1
TypeError: exec() globals must be a dict, not builtin_function_or_method
>>> print("nothing works")
TypeError: exec() globals must be a dict, not builtin_function_or_method
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot that `locals` is a function, so I needed to write:

```py
code.interact(local=locals())
```

instead of my erroneous:

```py
code.interact(local=locals)
```